# Apache 2.2, (MOD) SSL and Mod Rewrite via .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

What i want to do is the following,

1) Prevent normal non secure pages being shown as secure
2) Prevent secure pages being shown as normal non secure pages
3) Show secure pages as is, as specified by their links

Also note there are, ie ./contact/subscribe which is secure but not ./contact/welcome. I have tried several conditions and rules found on the web but I hit a wall - endless redirects, etc.

Appreciate any thoughts on this please as I'm getting no where :(

Answer (score 0):

Try some of these for example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  ## redirect anything that is not secure and is in folder secure-pages to the secure version
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^secure-pages/(.*)$ https://example.com/secure-pages/$1 [R=301,L]

  ## 301 redirect and force contact/subscribe to be secure
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^contact/subscribe$ https://example.com/contact/subscribe [R=301,L]

  ## 301 redirect and force contact/subscribe to be NOT secure
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteRule ^contact/welcome$ http://example.com/contact/welcome [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```